# How to change UIImageView's image based on UISwitch's state

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

My code successfully builds but shows an error:

> 2017-01-25 14:05:06.645 project 4[2500:109254] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key imagechg.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var switchController: UISwitch!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        print(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }

    @IBAction func switchimgchng(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if switchController.isOn == true {
            myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "appleBlack.png")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your error log error?????????

Comment: 2017-01-25 14:05:06.645 project 4[2500:109254] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<project_4.ViewController 0x7fb472604fa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imagechg.'

Comment: @sdp edit your post and the error in it please :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` issue.

Make sure you have connected them correctly.

For more reference check [this](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=26402207362092964539) demo.

And from your comment there is extra `@IBOutlet` connected with your `UIImageView` named `imagechg` so remove that. And connect correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably connected your imageview to a different IBOutlet before and renamed it in your class. Delete the outlet connection in your storyboard and link it again.